# Is there a way to simplify $\ln\left[ \Gamma\left( i x \right) \right] - \ln\left[ \Gamma\left( i y \right) \right]$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, logarithms, gamma-function

For two positive real numbers $x>0,y>0$ is there a way to simplify the following function?
$$
\ln\left[ \Gamma\left( i x \right) \right] - \ln\left[ \Gamma\left( i y \right) \right]
$$

I am tempted to put them into a single logarithm $\ln\left( \frac{\Gamma\left( i x \right)}{\Gamma\left( i y \right)} \right)$ but I don't think I can do this since the arguments of the logarithm are complex.

Comment: It is not much different from asking if there is a way to simplify $\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(y)}$ for $x,y>0$. If your task, as I believe, it to study the $\Gamma$ function over the imaginary axis, simply consider that $$\left|\Gamma(ix)\right|^2 = \Gamma(ix)\Gamma(-ix)=\frac{\pi}{x\sinh(\pi x)}$$ by the reflection formula.